# Выбор дополнительных решений для вебсайта

Tags: wordpress, api

У меня есть готовая верстка (обычный html+css) и я хочу на ней сделать сделать новую версию магазина. Предыдущая на вордпресс. В текущей версии очень много статики, потому что для заказов в магазине пользователю даже не нужно регистрироваться - он только оставляет e-mail для связи.

Как мне интересно сделать? У меня есть 2 проблемы, которые я хочу решить:

1. сделать сайт супер-быстрым
2. сделать url-адреса со своей собственной логикой без извращений, которые есть в wordpress-e

Как я хочу это сделать?
С точки зрения скорости я хочу сделать 90% страниц статичными. Я хочу разделить каждую страницу на области. Одна из них статичная (например, футер и карточка товара), а другая динамичная (например, корзина и меню админа, который может быть залогинен). Мне нужно 2 технологии:

- первая, которая позволит на вордпрессе кэшировать страницы, чтобы потом к ним обращаться и выгружать статику мгновенно без обращений к бд (возможно через API, но что-то мне подсказывает, что API вордпресса всегда будет обращаться к бд)
- вторая, которая позволит без особых заморачиваний настроить логику url-ов, создать шаблоны с "областями" и запустить сайт

Собственно вопрос - есть ли готовые решения по каждому пункту вместо того, чтобы писать все самому? Хотя у меня и есть дизайн, делать именно верстку под что-то не вариант, банально нет на это времени. Нужно именно простое решение, если верстка уже есть.

Comment: Что-то намудрено у Вас с вот той технологией которая должна кешировать и тп, может Вы так сложно описали. Вообще в таких случаях используют что-то вроде Next.js, Nuxt.js и тп. Что не так с URL тоже не совсем ясно, Rewrite Rules в помощь.

Comment: Гуглим "headless wordpress", впечатляемся и.... забиваем и делаем как положено :) Wordpress - уже готовое решение для создания сайта.